# Collecting values from form's widgets

Tags: c++, qt, data-structures, qt4, qt5

Given the following:

```
struct Property {
  QWidget *label;
  QWidget *field;
};
QList<Property*> properties;
```

In which most of the `field`s are `QLineEdit`s but some are `QTimeEdit`s and might be other kinds, like `QDateEdit`.

This is used to (conveniently) make a form this way:

```
for(int i = 0; i != properties.size(); i++)
    formLayout->addRow( properties.at(i)->label,properties.at(i)->field );
```

And I'm thinking in collect the values from the form's `field`s in the same fashion:

```
foreach (const Property *p, properties) 
    p->field->value()
```

The problem is there is no such `value()` function.

Is this design ok? Which should be the approach in order to achieve the `value()`?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of doing that.

1. An ugly approach would be to use the `p->metaObject()->className()` method.
2. A better way is to use `qobject_cast<Class*>(p)` for all possible types. The one that is not NULL is the right type.
3. You could use `p->inherits("CLASS")` to ask for inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

The naïve approach is hardcoding all the possibilities in advance, by employing something like:

```
if (QLineEdit *le = qobject_cast<QLineEdit *>(obj)) {
    le->text(); 
} else if (QDateTimeEdit *dte = qobject_cast<QDateTimeEdit *>(obj)) {
    dte->dateTime();
} else if (...) { // repeat for all the cases

}
```

---

The **proper** and **robust** approach is exploiting Qt's meta object capabilities. In particular, [a class can mark one of its properties to be the *USER* property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html), that is, the property that the user interacts with. This is done for Qt's own edit widgets.

So the good and general way is:

```
QVariant result;
QMetaObject *mo = obj->metaObject();
const int propertyCount = mo->propertyCount();
for (int i = 0; i < propertyCount; ++i) {
    QMetaProperty mp = mo->property(i);
    if (mp.isUser(obj)) { 
        result = mp.read(obj);
        break;
    }
}
// use result
```